# Resultado igual aos dois último caracteres dos registros

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Tentei criar um SQL para o MYSQL para consultar apenas os registros que contém os dois últimos caracteres, fiz assim:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `veiculos` WHERE `placa` LIKE '07%' ORDER BY `modelo` ASC;
?>
```

Mas o SQL ignora o LIKE não exibe nenhum registro, sem erros, apenas não exibe.

[EDITADO]

Depois troquei a posição do LIKE e apareceu o registro, apenas um, mas a outra dúvida que surgiu é, e se houver mais de um registro por exemplo XXX-0077, o SQL vai retornar ele também?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `veiculos` WHERE `placa` LIKE '%07' ORDER BY `modelo` ASC;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O '%07' vai retornar apenas os registros terminados com '07'.

Se o tamanho for fixo, você pode olhar também como funciona o underscore ( _ ).

Se quiser qualquer registro que possua '07' (Exemplo XXX-0077), usa '%07%'.